# What is default value for "optionLabel" of the HTML DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So if Set up a DropDownList where Text: `"people names" (string)`and Value:`studentID (int)`. in my view like this (assuming myDDL is data from code-behind placed in the viewbag)

```
     @Html.DropDownList("myDDL", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.myDDL,  
     "Select Stuff", new Dictionary<string,object>{
      {"class","dropdowns"},{"id","myDDL"}})
```

What is the value of "Select Stuff" which is an optional label that appears at the beginning of the dropdown list?

I'd like the value because it if no value is selected then I'd like to get all the data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's empty and it's always the first option of the dropdown, so make sure that you are binding it to a non-nullable property in the postback action:

```
<select name="selectedValue">
    <option value="">Select Stuff</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Also you seem to be using `myDDL` as both the first argument and the second of the dropdownlist helper which is wrong. The first argument is a property that would be used to get the selected value. The second is the available values and must be an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

So something like this would make more sense:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "selctedValue",
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.myDDL,
    "Select Stuff", 
    new { @class = "dropdowns", id = "myDDL" }
)
```

But what would really make sense and what I would recommend you is to get rid of this `ViewBag` and use a view model and the strongly typed version of this helper:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedValue,
    Model.MyDdlItems,
    "Select Stuff", 
    new { @class = "dropdowns", id = "myDDL" }
)
```

Comment: Is there any way to give it a value?

Comment: @EKet, no, there isn't, unless you write your custom `DropDownList` helper. The built in helper uses an empty string as default value for this option and you cannot change this. It's by design. Actually you shouldn't ever need to change this if you use view models as I suggested you.

Comment: your last method limits my view to a type, what are the advantages? What if I don't want to use only one model for my view. Seems like you're saying I should never use two types for one view...

Comment: @EKetm advantages are strong typing and Intellisense. And yes, I am saying that you should never use more than one type for a view. That's usually a design smell. If you wanted to handle multiple types in the view you would simple aggregate them as properties into a single view model root which is what your view will be strongly typed to. ViewBag/ViewData and weak typing that this induces is the worst thing that the Microsoft MVC team has ever introduced in his fantastic framework. I still continue to blame them for this decision. We see one manifestation of it here...

Comment: ... since you didn't use strongly typed helpers and view models you confused the usage of the DropDownList helper and passed it the same value as both the first argument and the second.

Comment: Interesting point, makes sense. So what you're saying is if a view has 2 types then those 2 types should really be a class composed of those 2 types. Could you then explain the last method you described. From what I get is, we have a type for the View. Then the dropdownlist takes the selected value and automatically filters the model?

Comment: @EKet, exactly, you have this: `public class MyViewModel { public string SelectedValue { get; set; } public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MyDdlItems { get; set; } }`. Now all you have to do is populate this view model and pass it to the view. If you set the value of the `SelectedValue` property to an existing value of the `MyDdlItems` collection the strongly typed `DropDownListFor` helper that you will use will automatically preselect it when rendering the view.

Comment: Wow awesome. Thanks Darin. You've enlightened my day.

Answer (score 3):

It's the empty string. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504970.aspx) covers this (emphasis mine):

> `optionLabel`
>
> > Type: `System.String`
> >
> > The text for a default **empty** item.
> >     This parameter can be null.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually try adding a fake value into your List of object inside of your dropdown list which take inn value = "None"/"select stuff" and id = 0. In which it will help you to generate a fake value where user is able to select on the value in the dropdown list and you should be able to handle it on the backend code. Hope this helps.